# How do I update matplotlib tick labels dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an animated graph that gets Network usage history and scales the y limits dynamically depending on the magnitude of the relevant data being passed. How do I get my y tick labels to reflect the changing y limits? Everything works fine when I set `blit=Flase` everything updates fine however I don't want everything to update every tick, just the y tick labels when the y limits change? So how do I just update or redraw the y tick labels?

```
def resize(self, y_data):
    cur_max = max(y_data)
    if cur_max > self.ax.get_ylim()[1]:  # if cur_max > upper y limit..
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1, cur_max + cur_max * .10)  # increase upper y limit to fit cur_max
        ### update/redraw tick labels? ###
    if self.ax.get_ylim()[1] * .25 > cur_max > 0:  # if 1/4 the upper y limit > cur_max and cur_max > 0...
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1, cur_max * .50)  # set upper y limit 1/2 its current size
        ### update/redraw tick labels? ###
```

Comment: When updating the ylabels, the graphed data must be updated as well. Let's assume you have ylimits (0,6) and a point at y=3. Then you update the ylimits to (0,10) the point, which initially was in the middle of the graph now needs to be in the lower part of it, correct? That said, it's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. Using `blit=False` seems fine to me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The scale of the data being graphed changes dramatically from a few bytes per second to many thousands per second depending on the network load. When it jumps to many thousand per second it adjusts they y limit to scale to the new y range that is appropriate for the incoming data thus making the previous graphed data that was in the tens of bytes per second insignificant.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The graphed line updates fine with the new y scale, effectively flattening the line where the data was in the 10's  and now only really showing peaks which are in the 1000's. The problem is that the y tick labels don't update when the y limit is changed, so the graphed lines data is in the 1000's but the y tick labels still show 1-100. However when i resize the window the y tick labels do update. So I guess a solution is to find which function is being called to redraw the axis/tick labels when the window is resized?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If you have access the the gnome system monitor, the network history graph is an example of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is to chose an appropriate tick locator and/or tick formatter : a function that is called to dynamically relocate the ticks and labels when the axis limits are changed.

all docs can be found here :
http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

You can use predefined locators (e.g. LinearLocator) or define your own locator following the example below :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

#- define the data
x = np.linspace(0., 1., 100)
y = np.random.randn(len(x))

#- plot it
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(x, y, 'k')

#- define your own locator based on ticker.LinearLocator
class MyLocator(ticker.LinearLocator):
   def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
       "vmin and vmax are the axis limits, return the tick locations here"
       return [vmin, 0.5 * (vmin + vmax), vmax]

#- initiate the locator and attach it to the current axis
ML = MyLocator()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ML)

plt.show()
#- now, play with the zoom to see the y-ticks changing
```